# How to determine a point is outside or inside

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

How could I determine a point is outside or inside of a domain with variable raduis. like this:

$$x(t)=(0.3+0.2(\sin3t))\cos t$$
$$y(t)=(0.3+0.2(\sin3t))\sin t$$

where 0$\leq t< 2\pi$.

I tried with  $r=0.3+0.2(\sin3t)$ and checked $x^2+y^2-r^2$, but it does not work.

Comment: This is a beautiful curve, indeed !

Comment: You need to use the correct $t$ for a given point $(x,y)$.

Comment: @lhf. Could you elaborate for me, please ? I did worked parametric curves for the last 40+ years, I guess. Thanks and cheers.:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is inside the curve, test whether $x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2<0$ for $r=0.3+0.2\sin3t$ with $t=\arg(x_0,y_0)=\mbox{atan2}(y,x)$. Here  [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) is used for converting between polar and Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. This remembers me that I have been young, loooong time ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It was a nice answer. I  really enjoyed.